# The remote name could not be resolved http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate

Tags: c#, email, smtp

**Full error**

> System.Exception: Error sending email (0 bytes): Mailbox unavailable.
>   The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to
>   send as this sender ---> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Mailbox
>   unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client does not have
>   permissions to send as this sender

I inherited a project five years ago, and it is at least six years old.  The project contains a couple of web applications and a few desktop apps & services.

The web application sends email pretty regularly, and it has been running without much in the way of problems until recently.

When we started getting this error, I tried a few things on my end.  I created a small test web app and deployed it on a separate server.  I used the same mail server, address, and credentials.  It works fine.  I also used dbmail on the same server the problem app is located, again using the same mail address.  It works also.

I've read maybe six or seven questions & answers on the subject here and elsewhere, to no avail.  It seems pretty clear that this is the mail server returning this error.  But why would SQL Server's dbmail and the test app I made send if that were the case?

Here is the connection information with a few changes for the sake of anonymity.

```
static void SendEmail(MailMessage msg)
{
    msg.Headers["http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate"] = "2";

    using (var c = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "mailserver.address.com",
        Port = 587,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("UserName", "password", "address.com"),
        EnableSsl = false,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
    })
    {
        try
        {
            c.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var size = msg.Attachments.Sum(a => a.ContentStream.Length);
            throw new Exception(string.Format("Error sending email ({0} bytes): {1}", size, ex.Message), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

What has greatly exacerbated the problem is that the source code I have for roughly half of these apps is clearly not the identical of the code deployed.  They had zero version control when I first started years ago.  So, I can't easily tweak around in the code and redeploy because it will break the entire application.  I would have to do a full-blown overhaul (and actually, I am, but it's not going to be ready anytime in the immediate future).

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

---

I've found the cause.

The port wasn't added in my test.  When added, it causes the error.

**Why would this break on a certain date this month?**

Comment: Do you have access to the mail server's log? Maybe it would reveal something.

Comment: Is the "from" in the web.config the same as your test app and other methods that work successfully? I don't see a From here.

Comment: The "from" is specified in the msg.  It's the same user for all messages.

Comment: I don't have access to the log @itsme86 but I sit close to the guys who do.  I've informed them and asked them to look at things from their end and they have found nothing.  Maybe they can send me the log.

Comment: I believe I've found the cause.  See above.  If you have any ideas they're greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the mail server admins shutdown 587 and you're just operating on good ol' port 25 now?

Comment: Turns out that yes this was a mail server issue as I was able to prove.  Thanks for all your help.  I'm pretty unknowledgeable about the mail server myself, but after some trial and error they got it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mail server issue.  A sysadmin is the only person that can fix this, and I was able to get them to resolve.  Thanks.